# How to create a picture that when clicked open email composer

Tags: html, image, email, hyperlink, mailto

I want to make an "Email Us" picture link at the bottom of my webpage. How do i make it so that it will compose a new email message?

Comment: You ask the question and answer it yourself?

Comment: Yes. Apparently you can do that. Did you vote it down? Is it not properly written?

Comment: Yes, I did. You can do that, but you have asked the question and answered it at the same time.

Comment: May I ask why you voted down? Is there something wrong with the question? I thought it might be a helpful question for the community. I know how to do this therefore I did not need it answered.

Comment: @jake1k We don't want users bloating the site with self-answered questions in order to boost their reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the HTML link code `<a href="mailto:example@yourdomain.com"><img src="picture_path.jpg" /></a>` And now your picture will open a new email message to `example@yourdomain.com` in the user's default email program.